# Send array to another activity, and display them in listview error

Tags: android, android-intent

Sending array to another intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this, Upload.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", selectImages);
                startActivity(intent);
```

What is the most simple way to get the data and pass to listview? 
This is an array, so i need to run a loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to send data from one activity :

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyOTP.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("user_name", user_name);// for single data
startActivity(intent);
```

For an Array you can use :

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Array", arrayNmae);
```

And use this in another activity's ***onCreate***

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent!=null) {
    user_name = intent.getStringExtra("user_name");
}
```

For array list use this :

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize an array
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent!=null) {
        array = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Array");
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: and how to display in a listview?

Comment: you can use ***getStringArrayListExtra*** insted of ***getStringExtra***

Answer (score 0):

To **send** array from one activity to another,

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("images", selectedImages);
```

To **receive** data,

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> selectedImages = bundle.getStringArrayList("images");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define static

```
public static someArray

//and access
Your_Activity.someArray
```